# KendoUI AreaChart bases category axis on first data group only

Tags: javascript, configuration, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I'm building my area chart series from groupings in my datasource and the categories from an aggregate of a date field to show the number of errors reported in our system.

in datasource config:

```
group: { // default grouping
    field: "Severity"
},
```

in chart config:

```
data-series="[ { 'type': 'area', 'field': 'ErrorId', aggregate: 'count' } ]"
data-category-axis="{ 'field': 'Logged', 'baseUnit': 'days', 'labels': { 'dateFormats': { 'days': 'd MMM' } } }"
```

but once the data is grouped the chart bases the category axis range on the values within the first group only. So if in my 1st group I only have records from 25th-November, but in the 2nd group there are records from as far back as 1st-November and every day since, the chart will only show a single day.

What I'd expect to happen is the chart to recognize that the 2nd group has values as far back as 25th-Nov and the (fictional) 3rd group maybe has a record from today, I'd expect the axis to show the date range 1st-Nov - 4-Dec rather then just the 25th-Nov.

Answer (score 2):

Very sad that such simple scenario is not supported. Looks like the chart reads only dates from the first series and expects all other series to have the exact same dates. See same problem with example: [Is this a bug? Stacking time series ignores the date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434391/is-this-a-bug-stacking-time-series-ignores-the-date-value)